# How too sort the values of an array in the result set in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have the query below to bring in multiple arrays from different sheets.  The problem is that they are sorted in their specific arrays but not the overall set.  Is there a way to sort them according to the value in the first column?  A sort at the start becomes a circular reference.

```
={unique(sort(filter('Durban KH'!D5:R497,NOT(ISBLANK('Durban KH'!F5:F497)))));unique(sort(filter('Richards Bay KH'!D5:R497,NOT(ISBLANK('Richards Bay KH'!E5:E497)))))}
```

Comment: Aside: not(isblank(...)) can be replaced by len(...) which is a bit shorter and has the same effect. As for a reason for circular reference, I don't see any in the fragment you've given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can apply `sort` function to an array composed with array notation `{...; ...}`. Here's a self-contained example:

```
=sort({{1,2;3,4}; {0,1;2,3}}, 1, true)
```

works as expected. Same for arrays obtained from the spreadsheet, like

```
=sort({A2:B9; C2:D9}, 2, false)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=SORT({unique(sort(filter('Durban KH'!D5:R497,NOT(ISBLANK('Durban KH'!F5:F497)))));unique(sort(filter('Richards Bay KH'!D5:R497,NOT(ISBLANK('Richards Bay KH'!E5:E497)))))})
```

I believe the reason your formula isn't sorting is because you need to add the sort function on the outside of your brackets you are current using in your formula

See the two attached images, the first one is an exact replica of your formula but point to random data I have in my own sheet, you can see how the two arrays are separated and sorted individually:

[image]

Then in the second one I re-wrap the whole formula with `Sort` and get this:

[image]

note: I would also swap your `Not(isblank())` portion for a single `istext()` instead:

```
=SORT({unique(sort(filter('Durban KH'!D5:R497,ISTEXT('Durban KH'!F5:F497))));unique(sort(filter('Richards Bay KH'!D5:R497,ISTEXT('Richards Bay KH'!E5:E497))))})
```